# Look And Feel getting changed on JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, look-and-feel

I have a swing application, that has its look and feel set to the custom L&F from the company at the main method, where the application is started.
The problem is: This works for ALL frames and windows, but somehow it doesn't work for JDialogs.

I've even manually set the L&F during the initialization of the dialog, but still get the platform dependent L&F.

Looking for answers or bugs that might explain this behavior, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735981/java-in-linux-different-look-and-feel-classes-for-root-and-non-root), that explains that the environment variables change the behavior of the UIManager, so I've set the variables `swing.crossplatformlaf` and `swing.systemlaf` to return my custom L&F, but still get the OS dependent L&F.

Is there something that I'm missing here? How can Swing configure a different L&F for just JDialogs? I'm having a different L&F on Linux and Windows because of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A component uses the LAF at the time the component is created. So you must set the LAF BEFORE creating any components, not when you initialize the dialog. Post a proper [mre] is you need more help.

Comment: @camickr I set the LAF during the initialization:
"java -Dswing.crossplatformlaf="com.mycompany.MyLookAndFeel" -Dswing.systemlaf="com.mycompany.MyLookAndFeel" ..."

Comment: If you set the style of the application inside the Main method or frame method with UIManager, your application doesn't have a personal L&F but have a personal Style.
The answer depends on your code and your l&f or your UIManager configuration